# How to handle concurrent requests in my API

Tags: mongodb, api, next.js

I have an API endpoint which manage available rooms in a Hotel. Every Time a customer make a POST/GET request to my API, I look for an available room and return the room number to them like this:

```
const db = await ConnectToDatabase(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
const collection2 = db.collection('rooms');

        var result = await collection2.findOneAndUpdate({
            isBusy: false
            },{
            $set:{
                isBusy: true
                customer: request.body.customer_id
            }
        })
   
        if(result == null)
        {
           return response.status(200).json({
            status: "FAIL",
            msg: "No avaible rooms"
        })}

        return response.status(200).json({
            status: "SUCCESS",
            room: result.room_number
        })
```

The problem is: When 30 people request rooms at the same time, my API usually sends the same room number to more than one customer. How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for anyone who is looking for a solution to this I had to create a queue system right before mongo call. Idk if there is anything better than this but this solved my problem (at least for now). If you have a better solution to this fell free to anwser here

Edit: I'm using a simple pessimist lock system to prevent this

Comment: I am going through same problem , are you using serial processing with queue? also, let me know if you are using some other approach now

Comment: @BhanuArora Pessimist lock fits well in my project but if you have to deal with massive access to sensitive content I guess you will have to use some mutex or semaphores, but I'm not sure if there is nothing better than this. GL